# comparison between txt and csv in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, txt

I have two files, one txt and one csv.
The txt look like

```
0.5 a 4d
1 b 5e
1.5 c 6f
```

the csv look like

```
h1 h2 h3

a  4d  1
b  5e  2
c  6f  3
```

what I want to do is to take the first column of the txt file and subtract it by the column 3 of the csv file then I will like to add the result to the corresponding value to the txt file

exemple:

for the first line I would like to do 1 - 0,5 = 0,5 then 0,5 + 0,5 = 1 in the text file. (the idea is to correct txt according to the csv one.)

I have some difficulties to perform this without using tmp files.

Comment: Please show the complete output.

Comment: Your example `do 1 - 0,5 = 0,5 then 0,5 + 0,5 = 1 in the text file.`  does not comply with the description ` to take the first column of the txt file and subtract it by the column 3 of the csv file then I will like to add the result to the corresponding value to the txt file`. ...